# SQL Query seemly returning an incomplete result set

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query returns many correct rows, but does not return a row for seed = '1985.00-Miller-13' (there are others missing too but this is just one example):

```
SELECT g.dam_alias "Seed" 
FROM genetic g LEFT OUTER JOIN (genetic g1d)
ON (g.dam_alias = g1d.genetic_alias)
GROUP BY g1d.dam_alias , g1d.sire_alias;
```

However if I add a WHERE clause to the query specifying the row that I think is missing, it shows up. Here is the modified query:

```
SELECT g.dam_alias "Seed"
FROM genetic g LEFT OUTER JOIN (genetic g1d)
ON (g.dam_alias = g1d.genetic_alias)
WHERE g.dam_alias = '1985.00-Miller-13' -- this is the added line
GROUP BY g1d.dam_alias , g1d.sire_alias;
```

If my original query indeed should not have returned the row for the seed "1985.00-Miller-13", I would have expected the second query to return no rows.

At first I suspected that my keys/indexes were corrupt and so I did a db dump and rebuilt from the resulting sql script. I have replicated the problem using MYSQL v5.6 and MariasDB v 10.0.17

I have hand inspected the data and walked through the query on paper and find nothing that is inconsistent with my expected results.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I can provide any additional information/schema/data that anyone might need.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much to everyone who commented. The comments were spot on and extremely helpful in getting me to understand what was going on and where my mistake lay. Adding g.dam_alias to the group by resolved the problem. Here is the fixed query:

Comment: SELECT g.dam_alias "Seed" 
FROM genetic g LEFT OUTER JOIN (genetic g1d)
ON (g.dam_alias = g1d.genetic_alias)
GROUP BY g.dam_alias, g1d.dam_alias , g1d.sire_alias;

Answer (score 2):

You're grouping on `g1d.dam_alias`, but selecting `g.dam_alias`.

Most other RDBMS products do not allow the selection of unaggregated columns from within a group, because it is ambiguous from *which* record within the group a value should be returned.  MySQL does however permit this operation as a performance enhancement, although the documentation is clear that the results in such cases are indeterminate:

See [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-handling.html) (emphasis added):

> MySQL extends the use of `GROUP BY` so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the `GROUP BY` clause. This means that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the `GROUP BY` are the same for each group. **The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.**

What's (presumably—we cannot say for certain without seeing the underlying data) happening is that `g.dam_alias = '1985.00-Miller-13'` exists within some groups, but different values of `g.dam_alias` from other records within those groups are selected instead.  When you add the filter, there are no other values to select and consequently the value that is selected is guaranteed to be the one you expect.

It's difficult to make a recommendation for fixing this problem without understanding the semantics of your desired query.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful. Let me digest this and see if I can't construct a different query that will meet my needs.

Comment: Thank you eggyal! Your very thorough response got me on the right page and the problem has been resolved by correcting my group by clause.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `left outer join` and the `group by` references the *second* table.  These values could be `NULL`.  Take the column from the first table:

```
SELECT g.dam_alias "Seed"
FROM genetic g LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     genetic g1d
     ON g.dam_alias = g1d.genetic_alias
GROUP BY g.dam_alias, g1d.sire_alias;
---------^
```

Comment: Besides having the same column name, there's nothing to suggest that `g.dam_alias = g1d.dam_alias` irrespective of the outer join (it's not a join criterion).

Comment: Thank you. I am taking all of this very useful advice and re-examining my query.

Comment: @eggyal . . . I was assuming it was a typo, actually.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. You were correct and once I corrected the GROUP BY clause, the problem was fixed.